# Sending a message from Java to a registered Erlang gen_server

Tags: erlang, jinterface

How does one go about sending a message from a Jinterface Java server to a globally registered gen_server?

For example, my gen_server was started like this:

```
  start_link ({global, myServerName}, Mod, Args, Options).
```

mbox.send("myServerName", MyMessage).  doesn't work.  No message arrives at myServerName:handle_info.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to invoke `global:send/2` as an RPC on the server node. The Java code would look like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.ericsson.otp.erlang.*;

public class JClient {
    static String server = "server";
    static String global = "myServerName";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OtpSelf client = new OtpSelf("client", "java");
        OtpPeer peer = new OtpPeer(server);
        OtpConnection conn = client.connect(peer);
        conn.sendRPC("global", "send", new OtpErlangObject[] {
                new OtpErlangAtom(global),
                new OtpErlangTuple(new OtpErlangObject[] {
                        new OtpErlangAtom("publish"),
                        new OtpErlangTuple(new OtpErlangObject[] {
                                new OtpErlangAtom("all"),
                                new OtpErlangString("this is a test")})
                    })});
    }
}
```

The second argument to the `OtpSelf` constructor is the Erlang cookie, which has to match the cookie of the server node as we'll see below. The code uses the `sendRPC` method of `OtpConnection` to call the `global:send/2` function on the server node, which returns the pid of the globally-registered process if it succeeds or an error if not (but the Java code doesn't check this).

The server could be a simple `gen_server` and look like this:

```
-module(svr).
-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([start_link/0, stop/0]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2,
         terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-record(state, {}).

start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({global, myServerName}, ?MODULE, [], []).

stop() ->
    gen_server:cast({global, myServerName}, stop).

init([]) ->
    {ok, #state{}}.

handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    {reply, ok, State}.

handle_cast(stop, State) ->
    {stop, normal, State};
handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info({publish, {Topic, Msg}}, State) ->
    io:format("publish for topic ~p: ~p~n", [Topic, Msg]),
    {noreply, State};
handle_info(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.
```

Note that I register the server with the global name `myServerName` to match what you used in your question, but in practice I never use mixed-case atom names like that.

To run the server, first start an Erlang shell:

```
erl -sname server -setcookie java
```

Note that the cookie matches what's in the Java code, and also that I used `-sname` to name the server node; I didn't try long names at all.

Then, run the `svr` process in the Erlang shell:

```
Erlang R16B03-1 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G)
(server@myhost)1> svr:start_link().
{ok,<0.42.0>}
```

Then, run the Java client, and the server should emit the following message:

```
publish for topic all: "this is a test"
```

The main drawback to this approach is that it has to go through the RPC server for each message. Another alternative would be to send an RPC to `global:whereis_name/1` to look up the pid of the registered process, and then send messages directly to it using `send` instead of `sendRPC`, but the drawback there is that if the globally-registered process dies and is restarted, the Java code will need to detect that the pid is no longer valid and redo the lookup.